# Turtlebot Kinect Arm Calibration display not working properly

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-fuerte, turtlebot-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the turtlebot with Fuerte and Ubuntu 12.04 Precise and I am trying to run the arm kinect calibration tutorial using an off-board kinect.  I follow the tutorial precisely, but when I launch the calibration, only an empty window appears, with no image inside.  Image processing is clearly taking place, because I can open the kinect camera in rviz, and check the that the checkerboard is being seen properly.  When placed correctly, the calibration attempts to proceed, asking me to move the tip of the gripper to point 1, but still no image appears from the calibration_kinect_checkerboard topic, and I have no way of completing the calibration without the numbered overlay.  In addition, once I place the checkerboard properly and it recognizes an image, the window changes size, turns from grey to black and displays small firefox symbols along the edge.   Has anyone else experienced this problem, or know how to go about fixing it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43800/turtlebot-kinect-arm-calibration-display-not-working-properly/) by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed this by just accessing the display on the laptop itself.  For some reason, it was not displaying properly on the workstation, but the laptop displayed it properly.  I am still having errors with the work station, but this allowed me to proceed with the process.

---

Originally posted by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) with karma: 122 on 2012-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0